# How to implement Onedrive filepicker inside Microsoft Teams App if it needs to use window.open?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams, onedrive, filepicker

I am trying to use [Onedrive Filepicker v8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/?view=odsp-graph-online) in my Microsoft Teams App. It is working flawlessly from browser. But if I try to access from Microsoft Teams Desktop, it is not working because Microsoft Teams Desktop is blocking `window.open` from opening popup for security reason. Currently I use the [local SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/samples/tree/master/samples/file-picking/sdk-pnptimeline) that's exist inside the [sample codes](https://github.com/OneDrive/samples) of how to use the filepicker.

Is there any alternative that I can use to open some kind of popup within Microsoft Teams Desktop? or Is there any sample about how to use Filepicker inside the teams app?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using task module you can open a popup in Teams app.

On popup using html input type file tag you can open a file picker.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".docx, .pdf, .xlsx">
```

Please refer below sample for opening a file picker on popup.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-sharepoint-file-viewer

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!

But do you know how to implement [Onedrive Filepicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/controls/file-pickers/?view=odsp-graph-online) in it? It's a complete web app for picking file from onedrive. I've tried to insert it as a url of the task module and nothing load.

Comment: Could you please refer below doc for implementation of filepicker for onedrive:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-picker?tabs=windows